# Clipping transformed images in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to display images in matplotlib transformed by a 3x3 matrix (using homogeneous coordinates). I have the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

class GenericTransform(mp.transforms.Transform):
    input_dims = 2
    output_dims = 2
    is_separable = False

    # expects a 3x3 matrix as a numpy array
    def __init__(self, matrix):
        super().__init__()
        self.matrix = matrix
        self.has_inverse = (np.linalg.det(matrix) != 0)

    def transform(self, values):
        # append 1 to each coordinate in `values`
        hvals = np.insert(values, 2, 1, axis=1)

        # do the transformations
        thvals = np.matmul(self.matrix, hvals.transpose()).transpose()

        # TODO: perspective divison?

        # get rid of extra dimension and return
        return thvals[:, 0:2]

    def transform_non_affine(self, values):
        return self.transform(values)

    def inverted(self):
        return GenericTransform(np.linalg.inv(self.matrix))



# add an image to the plot with a transformation
def addImage(filename, matrix):
    transform = GenericTransform(matrix)
    img = mpimg.imread(filename)
    imgShow = plt.imshow(img, alpha=1)
    imgShow.set_transform(transform + imgShow.get_transform())
```

I call `addImage` with an image filename and a matrix, then call `plt.show()`, and the transformation seems to be applied correctly. However, the image that gets drawn appears to be extended beyond what its bounds should be, as if to fill the axis-aligned box defined by the image's corners:
[image: transformed image goes beyond expected bounds]
The line where there appears to be a "reflection" is where I want the image to simply be cut off. I'm not too familiar with matplotlib, so I'm confused as to why this happens. I was loosely following [this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/demo_affine_image.html). I also tried manually clip the image using a path:

```
# add an image to the plot with a transformation
def addImage(filename, matrix):
    transform = GenericTransform(matrix)
    img = mpimg.imread(filename)
    x = img.shape[1]
    y = img.shape[0]
    path = transform.transform_path(mp.path.Path([[0,0], [x,0], [x,y], [0,y], [0,0]]))
    patch = mp.patches.PathPatch(path, facecolor="none")
    imgShow = plt.imshow(img, alpha=1, clip_on=True, clip_path=patch)
    imgShow.set_transform(transform + imgShow.get_transform())
```

but this didn't quite work how I wanted. Specifically, whenever I resized the window or moved the plot around, the clipped areas remained stationary as the image in the background moved. How can I get it to clip my image correctly?

Also, I'm aware that the way I do the transformations might be wrong for perspective transformations, but I'd like to figure that out on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few hours, I finally figured it out. I didn't quite understand how transformations were being applied to the clip path. Ultimately, this worked:

```
def addImage(filename, matrix):
    transform = GenericTransform(matrix)
    img = mpimg.imread(filename)
    imgShow = plt.imshow(img, alpha=1, clip_on=True, interpolation="bilinear")
    oldTransform = imgShow.get_transform()
    imgShow.set_transform(transform + oldTransform)

    w = img.shape[1]
    h = img.shape[0]
    path = transform.transform_path(mp.path.Path([[0,0], [w,0], [w,h], [0,h], [0,0]]))
    patch = mp.patches.PathPatch(path, facecolor="none")
    patch.set_transform(oldTransform)
    imgShow.set_clip_path(patch)
```